# No puedo ejecutar sqlite3 en cmd

Tags: sqlite, cmd, shell

Quiero usar una base de datos sqlite, pero al intentar ejecutar el comando

```
>sqlite3
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
"sqlite3" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Ya verifiqué y la ruta que está en las variables del sistema es correcta.

Si ejecuto `sqlite3` en la ruta en donde descomprimí en `.zip` el resultado es el esperado, pero fuera no funciona.

Comment: Comparte el resultado de `echo %PATH%`, y verifica que la ruta donde tienes sqlite este ahi.

Comment: Está solucionado:  el comando ```echo %PATH%``` por alguna rozón me dice que sqlite se encuentra en ```C:\Windows\System32\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3360000``` en lugar de la que le establecí manualmente